# Spanish characters in ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm a `ggplot2` big fan, but I'm currently trying `ggvis`, because I'm also a big fan of `dplyr`. My problem is that I'm from a Spanish speaking country and I need to use Spanish characters, namely `áéíóúñ`

I'm trying the next code:

```
iris %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~Petal.Width, y = ~Petal.Length) %>% 
  layer_points(opacity := .8) %>% 
  add_axis('x', title = 'Ancho del pétalo') %>% 
  add_axis('y', title = 'Longitud del pétalo')
```

With this result:

[image: this result]

Notice the question marks where the character *é* should be. How can I get this character to be displayed? I've already tried changing the file encoding to UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1.

Comment: It works ok for me. Try this: `Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")`

Comment: I'm still getting the same result. I also tried `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "C")` but it changes `é` for `i`. Something similar happens with other special characters

Comment: Could you please include `sessionInfo()`? I had the same problem, however, the problem was that I was running RStudio on a 32 bit system at work. I tried it at my Mac at home and the letters were fine.